# How can I change file name color on desktop?

Tags: macos

I'm using a white background picture. How can I change the color of the text for items on my desktop to black?

Bonus points if there is a way to turn the shadow off too.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the answer is *almost* no.

The only hack I could find is:

In `Accessability > Display`, checking `Invert colors` will make the text invert color.

This obviously has side effects of everything else changing color in a sometimes unpleasant way. You'd have to use an originally black background to get a white background in this case.